# timthumb for python?

Tags: python, django

Is there a [TimThumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) - like script for Django/Python?

It's a image crop&rezise&cache script. Simple but very effective, imho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good django-app for that

http://thumbnail.sorl.net/

```
from sorl.thumbnail import get_thumbnail

im = get_thumbnail(my_file, '100x100', crop='center', quality=99)
```

Comment: lol ok it *is* simple, but the timthumbs is even simpler ;)    
+1 for the example, though

Answer (score 2):

You should take a closer look at [easy_thumbnails](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/easy-thumbnails/1.0-alpha-16).
It should do what you want.

And you can find more django related image tools in this grid on django packages:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/photos/